# Regex for find digits and character but at start have $ in string

Tags: php, regex

I have written a regex:

```
\s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*[mkb]?\s*
```

This regex fetches strings like `$100`, `$1k`, `$1m` or `$1b`.

It works fine but now I need it to return `$1mm` if there is `$1mm` in the string, not just `$1m` that is a part of `$1mm`.

Comment: Clarification: When `$1mm` and `$1m` appear in the string, should both be matched or just `$1mm`?

Comment: just need to match $1mm
if $1m came than it should read as $1 . 
all the stuff is working but need to replace $1m to $1mm

Comment: See [`\s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*(?:mm|[mkb]?)`](https://regex101.com/r/XHeS8V/2) demo. Is that what you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't undestand the difference - that is OP's regex https://regex101.com/r/OJd3xe/1

Comment: Also, what patterns are you trying to match with all those commas?

Comment: the above one which you have posted working fine but i made slight change
here is mine 
\s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*(?:mm|[kb]?)\s*
(actually your one reads $1m as well don't need that)
----
need another help your man . thanks in advance


@WiktorStribiżew
i also want to read MM or mm as well
e.g user can enter $1mm or $1MM how we can add condition on that?

i was using this when read $1m \s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*[mkMK]?\s*

Comment: See [`\s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*(?:mm|[kb]?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/XHeS8V/6) or even [`'~\s*\$\d[,.\d]*(?:mm|[kb]?)\b~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/XHeS8V/8)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Thanks man for your help i have use this regex .
\s*\$\d+\,?\.?\d*\,?\d*(?:mm|[mkb]?)(?:MM|[kMb]?)\s*

what this regex reads is
$1 , $1k , $1m , $1mm , $1MM , $1b and $1B

Comment: @waleed.mirza I posted an answer with explanations, and I added `\s*` at the end if you really need to have trailing spaces in the match. I also modified the question text, please edit if you think I changed it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\s*\$\d[,.\d]*(?:mm|MM|[mkbMKB]?)\b\s*~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHeS8V/11).

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` symbol
- `\d` - 1 digit
- `[,.\d]*` - 0+ digits, `,` or `.` chars
- `(?:mm|MM|[mkbMKB]?)` - either `mm`, `MM`, or case insensitively `k`, `m` or `b`, or empty string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: your answer is 90% correct but it not reads capital M ($1M or $1MM)
it you can changes it to
\s*\$\d[,.\d]*(?:mm|[mkbMKB]?)(?:MM|[mkbMKB]?)\b\s*

than i can mark this as correct otherwise i have to answer by my-self

Comment: @waleed.mirza Do you need to make the pattern case sensitive? `'~\s*\$\d[,.\d]*(?:mm|MM|[mkbMKB]?)\b\s*~'` won't match `$55Mm`.

Comment: o sorry i forgot to make case sensitive ON.

Comment: @waleed.mirza If you add `~i` you will match `$56Mm`, too.  Then just use `'~\s*\$\d[,.\d]*(?:mm|[mkb]?)\b\s*~i'`